# Why Colorize trait method can be called on String, while String doesn't impl Colorize

Tags: rust

From `Colorize` trait [doc](https://docs.rs/colored/2.0.0/colored/trait.Colorize.html), `String` doesn't impl it (whereas &str impls it).

```rust
fn blue(self) -> ColoredString
where
    Self: Sized,
```

But why `String` type can call its method?

```rust
use colored::Colorize;

fn main() {
    let blue = "blue".to_owned().blue();
    println!("{}", blue);
}
```

---

edits

- **[unresolved]** How can I desugar it? (specifically, to figure out auto deref is happening)
- What's happening under the hood?

Type coercion on method calls. `String` can be coerced to `&str` by `&*String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trait `Colorize` is implemented for `&'a str`, and `String` implements `Deref<Target=str>`.

Rust method call rules mean that the value might automatically be borrowed or dereferenced.

This means that for our method call on `String`, Rust will look for some method that has one of the following types as a receiver type

- `String`
- `&String`
- `&mut String`
- `str` (by deref)
- `&str` (this one lets the method call work)
- `&mut str`

---

Since the `String` is only being borrowed, you can use it after calling `.blue()`

```rs
use colored::Colorize;

fn main() {
    let x = "hello".to_string();
    let y = x.blue();

    println!("{}", x);
    println!("{}", y);
}
```

---

[link to rust reference regarding how method calls are resolved](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html)

Comment: I think `x` is moved as it's called in `blue` since it receives `self`.  Right, it's type coercion! Hard to remember those sugars.

Comment: `x` is not moved, since `self` is `&str`, and shared references are `Copy`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason `String` seems to support the traits implemented for `&str` is due to its implementation of `Deref` with the target type of `str`. String itself doesn't really support these traits, but the `.` operator acts as a sort of dereference giving access to the methods supported by `&str`.

Below is the minimal amount of code needed to isolate and demonstrate the same behavior.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum ColoredString { Blue }

trait Colorize {
    fn blue(self) -> ColoredString
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        ColoredString::Blue
    }
}

impl Colorize for &str { }  // <-- `Colorize` only impl'd for `&str`.

fn main() {
    let s = "a string".to_string();
    println!("{:?}", s.blue());     // <-- Invoking `.blue()` on `String`
}
```

output

```
Blue
```

By implementing `Colorize` for `&str`, `.blue()` can be invoked on `String`. If we implement `Deref` for an arbitrary struct in the same way `String` does, we should be able to reproduce the same behavior.

```rust
        :   // Continued from above example...
        :
impl Colorize for &str { }  // <-- `Colorize` only impl'd for `&str`.

use std::ops::Deref;

struct Foo { }              // <-- Arbitrary struct.

impl Deref for Foo {        // <-- Implements `Deref<Target = str>`.
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
        "I am Foo!"
    }
}

fn main() {
    let f = Foo { };
    
    println!("{:?}", &*f);          // <-- Simple deref.
    println!("{:?}", f.blue());     // <-- Invoking `.blue()` on `Foo`.
}
```

output

```
"I am Foo!"
Blue
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c2717eba69c6623afbd4840c0fae87c)

And it works; `Foo` above supports `Colorize` in the same way `String` does by implementing `Deref` with `Target = str`.

`Foo` doesn't actually support the `Colorize` trait at all - it just returns a `&str` when dereferenced, which the compiler takes into account when resolving the method call.

Comment: but reading the source of `colored`, it only impls for `&str`.

Comment: in this case, it's hard to expand it due to the orphan rule; I don't own colored nor String source. It turns out that this is related to type coercion on method calls.

Comment: @Izana ah I see.. I'm looking at the sources now and I see there's no explicit `impl Colored for String`, but somehow the compiler is fine with invoking the trait on a String.

Comment: Okay @Izana... I have an isolated example for the magic that happens. And in my example I got an arbitrary struct to support `Colorize` using the same mechanism that gives `String` the same trait support.